# Rust stacked optional in while let

Tags: rust

I am really new in rust, and while going through the rustlings exercises I found something I do not fully understand regarding stacked Options.

Given the following code:

```
let vector = vec![Some(24), None, Some(42)];
let mut iter = vector.iter();
while let Some(Some(number)) = iter.next() {
    println!("Number: {}", number);
}
```

I would expect to see the following output:

```
Number: 24
Number: 42
```

But I guess as soon as rust encounters the `None`, the while loop exits, only printing the 24

What would be the most idiomatic rust code to iterate and unwrap optional values?
The closest that I got would look something like this:

```
let mut iter = vector.iter();
while let Some(iterNext) = iter.next() {
    if let Some(num) = iterNext {
        println!("Number: {}", num);
    }
}
```

Or it could also be done by checking the existence in a for loop:

```
for opt in &vector {
    if opt.is_some() {
        println!("Number: {}", opt.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, when it encounters the second element, which is `Some(None)`, the `while` loop breaks. What is "more idiomatic" is more or less a matter of opinion, but I would definitely prefer the `if let` instead of the `is_some` / `unwrap` version. The whole point of `if let` is so that you can avoid manually checking / unwrapping the option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would expect to see the following output: [...]

A `while` loop that encounters a false condition exits - but that's not specific to Rust, it's just how `while` loops work.

An idiomatic solution would probably combine your last two snippets:

```
for opt in &vector {
    if let Some(num) = opt {
        println!("Number: {}", num);
    }
}
```

Just a simple `for` loop containing an `if let`, no unwrapping required.

Another idiomatic variant is to use iterator adapters:

```
vector
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|opt| opt.as_ref())
    .for_each(|num| println!("{}", num));
```

Note that here we could use `filter(Option::is_some)`, but then we would be left with options and would have to use `unwrap()` to get to the values. This is where
[`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) comes in useful: it filters the `Some` values (after applying the map function), and at the same time extracts the values inside. [`opt.as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) serves to trivially convert `&Option<T>`, obtained from iterating a vector of options by reference, to `Option<&T>` which `filter_map` expects returned.

Comment: @Friedman Clippy disagrees that this is an ideomatic solution [**warning: unnecessary `if let` since only the `Some` variant of the iterator element is used**] – whereas my solution passes as correct.

Answer (score 10):

Another nice way to write this code is

```
for num in vector.iter().flatten() {
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

The `flatten()` method on an iterator treats each item of the iterator as an iterator, and returns an iterator over all these iterators chained together. `Option` is an iterator that yields one element if it is `Some`, or none for `None`, so `flatten()` is exactly what we want here.

Of course you could also write this using `for_each()`, but for code with side effects I generally prefer `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

[Since Rust 1.65.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements), you can use a `let`-`else` statement, which saves you one level of indentation for the loop's body:

```rust
for opt in &vector {
    let Some(num) = opt else { continue };

    println!("Number: {}", num);
}
```